# how to sync smf forun and joomla databases?

Tags: joomla, forums, smf

I need to sync data from Joomla to SMF database dynamically. If someone logs in or registers in Joomla, something will happen in the SFM forum.  Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the work of [JoomlaHack](http://www.joomlahacks.com) team, especially at their [Joomla-SMF bridge](http://www.joomlahacks.com/component/option,com_remository/Itemid,41/func,select/id,13/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the bridge by Joomlah**** is quite old and outdated. I would recommend jFusion instead: http://www.jfusion.org/

Here's the link for SMF-specific instructions: http://www.jfusion.org/docs#smf

JED listing has positive reviews. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication-bridges/3723